# is there a database of known chemical reactions?

Tags: reference-request, cheminformatics

I am looking for a complete directory of chemical reactions. It should be searchable by element or substance and also the various factors (pressure, temperature, catalyst, etc) should be mentioned. Is there something like this? Thanks!